# docker: SSH access directly into container

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualization, docker

Up to now we use several linux users:

- system_foo@server
- system_bar@server
- ...

We want to put the system users into docker container.

- linux user `system_foo` --> container `system_foo`

The changes inside the servers are not problem, but remote systems use these users to send us data.

We need to make `ssh system_foo@server` work. The remote systems can't be changed.

I would be very easy if there would be just one system per linux operating system (pass port 22 to the container). But there are several.

How can we change from the old scheme to docker containers and keep the service `ssh system_foo@server` available without changes at the remote site?

Please leave a comment if you don't understand the question. Thank you.

Comment: so you want one container per connection? Can't you just configure `docker run` as the users shell in `etc/passwd`?

Comment: Have I got this correct?: You want to create a Virtual Machine like environment. So that each user has his own Container(VM) and the user can ssh into it and do what ever wanted.

Comment: @ZeissS yes, maybe a simple wrapper script in `/etc/passwd` is enough. I need to investigate if port forwarding and subprotocol sftp are working, too. Thank you for this "answer".

Comment: @beginer Yes, ssh to the account was allowed before and should be allowed after our internal change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's remember however that having ssh support in a container is typically an anti-pattern (unless it's your container only 'concern' but then what would be the point of being able to ssh in. Refer to http://techblog.constantcontact.com/devops/a-tale-of-three-docker-anti-patterns/ for information about that anti-pattern

Comment: Yes, it is an anti-pattern. That's why we won't use docker in our case.

Answer (score 2):

**nsenter** could work for you. First **ssh** to the host and then **nsenter** to the container.

```
PID=$(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} <container_name_or_ID>)`
nsenter --target $PID --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid
```

**source** http://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the comments, you might be looking for a solution like [`dockersh`](https://github.com/Yelp/dockersh). `dockersh` is used as a login shell, and lets you place every user that logins to your instance into an isolated container.

This probably won't let you use `sftp` though.

Note that `dockersh` includes security warnings in their README, which you'll certainly want to review:

> WARNING: Whilst this project tries to make users inside containers
>   have lowered privileges and drops capabilities to limit users ability
>   to escalate their privilege level, it is not certain to be completely
>   secure. Notably when Docker adds user namespace support, this can be
>   used to further lock down privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Some months ago, I helped my like this. It's not nice, but works. But
pub-key auth needs to be used.

Script which gets called via `command` in `.ssh/authorized_keys`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
import subprocess
cmd=['ssh', 'user@localhost:2222']
if not 'SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND' in os.environ:
    cmd.extend(sys.argv[1:])
else:
    cmd.append(os.environ['SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND'])
sys.exit(subprocess.call(cmd))
```

file system_foo@server: .ssh/authorized_keys

```
command="/home/modwork/bin/ssh-wrapper.py" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAAB...
```

If the remote system does `ssh system_foo@server` the SSH-Daemon at `server` executes the comand given in `.ssh/authorized_keys`. This command does a ssh to a different ssh-daemon.

In the docker container, there needs to run ssh-daemon which listens on port 2222.

Comment: It seems SSH and docker should not be used together: http://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/